# External controllers for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hardware

Are there any external buttons/controls that can be plugged into the iPhone that can be used within an app. If so, does anyone have any links to any code to use with these controls.

I was thinking of some kind of iPod controller that I could hack that could be plugged into the slot on the bottom of the phone.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Several USB MIDI controllers are supported via the Camera Connection kit on stock OS iOS devices.  An app can use CoreMIDI in/out messages to get input from the buttons on these external MIDI controllers.

But an app can't use a generic hackable USB input device under the stock OS, unless the developer is the manufacturer and also a member of Apple's MFi program.

ADDED:

...or you hack the USB device so that it imitates one of Apple's supported MIDI devices.  Example of doing this with an AVR microcontroller is [here](http://www.kotiposti.net/sodacan/coremidi/).

Apple's CoreMIDI reference is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/_index.html).

ADDED #2:

If you want even more accuracy for a timer app, consider using the mic audio input jack, and connecting some buttons to audio chirp generators (could be done either with analog circuitry or a tiny cheap micro).  Use different chirp frequencies for different buttons.  Some suitable DSP code on the iPhone could probably determine the relative timings of audio input chirp signals with sub-millisecond accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this, most involve jailbreaking the iphone.

The most famous/popular is the [iControlPad](http://icontrolpad.com/).

Comment: Can it not be done to an unjailbroken phone? I want to use an external control to start and stop a timer app I want to make for the iphone.